# Select aggregate data from one table between 2 date columns on row by row basis from data in another unrelated table

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL version 5.6

I have a soil sample table and a weather table which are unrelated other than dates. I collect soil samples once to twice a week and weather data every 5 minutes(24/7).

I am trying aggregate the AVERAGE temperature and the SUM of rainfall between consecutive soil sample dates.

Soil Sample Query

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SET @firstDate = CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()),'-03-01 00:00');
SELECT
   ObsDate,
   StartDateTime, 
   EndDateTime
FROM (
   SELECT
      ObsDate,
      @firstDate AS StartDateTime, 
      @firstDate:=ObsDateTime AS EndDateTime,
      row_num
   FROM(
      SELECT
         ObsDate,
         CONCAT(`ObsDate`, ' ', `ObsTime`) AS ObsDateTime,
         (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS row_num  
      FROM tblSoilSample
      WHERE ObsDate >= CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()),'-03-01 00:00' AND ObsDate <  CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()),'-10-01 00:00')     
      ) AS a
   GROUP BY ObsDate
   ORDER BY row_num
   ) as b
WHERE row_num > 1
```

This produces this result (limited to 2 rows)

```
ObsDate     StartDateTime           EndDateTime     
2022-05-21  2022-05-14 09:00    2022-05-21 09:30
2022-05-24  2022-05-21 09:30    2022-05-24 08:00
```

The weather data query

```
    SELECT 
        WxDateTime,
        TempOutCur,
        RainCur
    FROM  weatherbridge
    WHERE WxDateTime >= CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()),'-03-01 00:00') AND WxDate <= NOW()
```

Results (sample data) blank lines match soil dates

```
WxDateTime       TempOutCur RainCur
5/14/2022 08:29  49.1       0.01

5/14/2022 10:25  60.1       0.00
5/14/2022 18:15  58.8       1.10
5/15/2022 09:00  63.0       0.00
5/16/2022 12:35  57.7       1.23
5/17/2022 23:45  46.3       0.00

5/21/2022 10:50  55.8      0.00
5/22/2022 22:55  55.2      0.48
5/23/2022 13:00  68.2      0.01
5/24/2022 03:05  54.7      0.61
5/24/2022 05:20  54.3      0.00

5/24/2022 13:30  54.1      0.92
```

The output I am trying to achieve

```
ObsDate      AvgIntervalTemp    TotalIntervalRain   
2022-05-21   57.2               2.33
2022-05-24   57.6               1.10
```

This is one attempt that shows what I am trying to do, but prefer not to have a select within a select.

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SET @firstDate = CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()),'-03-01 00:00');
SELECT
    ObsDate,
    (SELECT AVG(TempOutCur) FROM wx WHERE WxDateTime >= StartDateTime AND WxDateTime <= EndDateTime) AS IntervalTemp,
    (SELECT SUM(RainCur) FROM wx WHERE WxDateTime >= StartDateTime AND WxDateTime <= EndDateTime) AS IntervalRain
FROM (
   SELECT
       ObsDate,
       StartDateTime, 
       EndDateTime
   FROM (
      SELECT
         ObsDate,
         @firstDate AS StartDateTime, 
         @firstDate:=ObsDateTime AS EndDateTime,
         row_num
      FROM(
         SELECT
            ObsDate,
            CONCAT(`ObsDate`, ' ', `ObsTime`) AS ObsDateTime,
            (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS row_num  
         FROM tblSoilSample
         WHERE ObsDate >= CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()),'-03-01 00:00' AND ObsDate <  CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()),'-10-01 00:00')     
         ) AS a
     GROUP BY ObsDate
     ORDER BY row_num
   ) AS b 
   WHERE row_num > 1
) AS c
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        WxDateTime,
        TempOutCur,
        RainCur
    FROM  weatherbridge
    WHERE WxDateTime >= CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()),'-03-01 00:00') AND WxDate <= NOW())  as wx
ON b.ObsDate = wx.WxDate
```

Comment: You use user-defined variables incorrectly. The query is not deterministic, it may return the expected output only randomly.

Comment: @Akina, I understand deterministic, but could you  be more informative on how I am using the user-defined variables incorrectly? I am not sure how this is solving my original question. Txs.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), especially "5. Some Additional Suggestions", "3. Show Your Expected Outcome" and maybe "C. Consider providing an SQL Fiddle or DB Fiddle".